# bash--compare wc output for greater than or equal to value

Tags: bash

Bash scripting: I need to compare the output of `wc -l` with a variable--to match greater than or equal to that variable.  The following code doesn't work but shows what I am trying to do.

```
#!/bin/bash
minimum_finds=1
found=$(locate this_is_the_file_i_want.txt|wc -l)

if [[ $found >= $minimum_finds ]]; then
  echo "Minimum met"
fi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please use concise and modern [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
if ((found >= minimum_finds)); then
```

Check [*bash arithmetic*](https://web.archive.org/web/20230224010517/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr)

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: Add `83.243.40.67 wiki.bash-hackers.org` in `/etc/hosts`

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/12klulf/comment/ji87xkk/?context=3

Comment: That's not a good temporary general solution, both because I'm not comfortable adding an arbitrary IP address to my hosts file just to follow a link, and because according to that thread, there's no guarantee that the IP will still be valid and pointing to the wiki server even a month from now. The better temporary alternative is to use web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20230224010517/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr

Comment: Post updated accordingly

Answer (score 10):

Replace `>=` with `-ge` (greater-than-or-equal)

---

See: `help test`